# Jquery load() hang

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Admittedly, I'm just getting around to learning jquery and I have an issue where a page hangs when I load it into a div box using load(). It works fine when accessing the page directly.

The load code looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#content").load("content/home.php");
  $('ul#nav li a').click(function() {
    var page = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#content').load('content/' + page + '.php');
    return false;
  });
  $('div#header-content a').click(function() {
    var page = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#content').load('content/' + page + '.php');
    return false;
    });
    $('div#content a').click(function() {
      var page = $(this).attr('href');
      $('#content').load('content/' + page + '.php');
      return false;
    });
});
```

With the actual page loaded into the specific div, executing another js:

```
<?php
  include('../xcrud/xcrud/xcrud.php');
  $xcrud = Xcrud::get_instance();
  $xcrud->table('User');
?>
<html>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text.html; charset=utf-8" />
  <body>
    <?php
      echo $xcrud->render();
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

The direct link to the working site is [here](http://www.khaledkloub.com/projects/ISM/content/editusers.php).
However, when you go to [the main site](http://www.khaledkloub.com/projects/ISM/navigator.php) and click "Edit Users" the div will hang indefinitely.

EDIT: I've managed to find some code that was being called that wasn't there, removed it, and now it loads. The issue is it takes a few seconds when it shouldn't.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors or other messages in your browser's console?

Comment: This won't fix anything, but you have a stray `</a>`. http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.khaledkloub.com%2Fprojects%2FISM%2Fnavigator.php&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: 1. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < ` in jquery.js:612 2. I'd suggest omitting all unnecessary code (`<html>`, `<head>` etc) for AJAX requests (you can easily determine AJAX requests by using `!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'`) 3. The delay is probably from loading `jquery-1.10.2.min.map` (and not finding it as the paths are relative)

Comment: This site works to me (windows/google chrome).

Comment: Thanks for that, it was just a misnamed jquery map file.

Comment: Ok, your site have several SQL Injection holes, hope you're going to correct them.

Answer (score 1):

The file `http://www.khaledkloub.com/projects/ISM/default.js?_=1395938319439` does not exist. It's returning a 404 with some content that is definitely not javascript, causing js execution to break.

Additionally, the file `http://www.khaledkloub.com/projects/ISM/xcrud/xcrud/plugins/jquery-1.10.2.min.map` also does not exist.